# android- How to detect double tap on imageview and start new fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, motionevent, gesturedetector

I have done a lot of search over the topic and have even referred the official documentation from android developer website. But still not clear with the concept.

I have read that for implementing the touch gestures i need to use the GestureDetector and MotionEvent packages. But its implementation kept me confusing over the things.

What i simply want is, my layout includes a many of textviews along with two imageviews. I want to detect a double tap on my images and want to start a new fragment activity. In the new fragment activity i want to show the same image in full screen in landscape mode.

I have done ton of reading but it kept me confusing.
Please help.
Thank you

Comment: please show what you had tried. there are several working examples available there.

Comment: Refer this Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection

You will get it.

Comment: @SilentKiller I havent yet tried anything it. I am just trying to learn it first

Comment: @user3794646 then you should first do Googling then should post question on SO. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is Double Tap Gesture ImageView.

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
    private Context context;
    private GestureListener mGestureListener;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mGestureListener=new GestureListener();
        Log.e("Adding", "Listener:::");
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, mGestureListener, null, true);
        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                //..my other code logic
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }

        });
    }

    public class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap( MotionEvent e ) {
            // TODO DoubleTap Comparison 
            Log.e("onDoubleTap","onDoubleTap");
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350054/add-double-tap-listener-to-my-custom-imageview)

Comment: i want to add it on specific imageview objects. will the above code work in desired direction?

Comment: I want to do something like android does in settings to go into Developer mode. How that can be implemented. If user taps 7 times on a imageview or any view. Then only do certain thing otherwise nothing.